# how to get access token using the consumer-key and consumer-secret in wso2 AM

Tags: types, oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager, sql-grant

I started learning wso2 AM and trying with the sample application which WSO2 provided  "pizzashake". As per the sample application I successfully got the access token. But I am tying to implement with different Authentication type which is by passing consumer key and consumer key alone.

But I am unable to get access token from WSO2 through my web application. I am getting 404 error - no matching resources found when I hit url.

below is the code :

```
 Srting submitUrl = http://localhost:8280/token

 String payloads = "response_type=token"+"&client_id="+consumerKey+"&scope=PRODUCTION";
            HttpReponse httpResponse = httpClient.doPost(submitUrl,consumerKey,
                    payload,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Any thoughts? How to get access token using consumer-key?

Answer (score 1):

You may use client credentials grant type to generate an access token. Send a POST request to http://localhost:8280/token in the following format.

Headers:
Authorization: Basic auth_string
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Payload:
grant_type=client_credentials

For "auth_string", you have to use the base64 encoded value of "client_key:client_secret"